# Open up specific URL in Auth Controlled Folder

Tags: apache-2.2

I have basic HTTP auth configured to a specific `Location` in my Apache config like:

```
<Location /system>
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Password Required"
  AuthUserFile /to/passwd/file
  Require valid-user
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from xxx
  Allow from xxx
  Satisfy Any
</Location>
```

with `/system` aliasing a folder which goes to a path `/system`.

Now I have a URL in this `/system` path of `/system/user/synchro` which I need to be public to everyone. It should be noted that the destination of the path is not a physical file but rather a rewritten URL.

Is there a way to nest a `Location` (or something) to be able to open up this one path but keep the rest locked down?